# Where is phpmyadmin installation folder used by azure app service which use MySQL In App database?

Tags: azure, phpmyadmin, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-appservice

I have an Azure App Service which uses MySQL In App as its database to serve WordPress site. I can see phpMyAdmin after I click Manage link like in the picture below:
[image]

But I need to access the phpMyAdmin installation folder and change it's config.inc.php so I can increase the max execution time limit & max upload size. Where is the phpMyAdmin installation folder for this case? I've searched in Kudu but failed to find it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: @JasonPan thanks for your answer. But I'm in holiday and I had different solution a week ago. I can't try your solution yet. Please don't disturb me with your comments. I will try your solution once I have time

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

**Step 1. Add `phpMyAdmin Extension` in portal.**

[image]

**Step 2. Open kudu, then  you can find the file you want under the folder `D:\home\SiteExtensions\phpmyadmin>`.**

[image]